# Can't load data from inversed side

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, relationships

I've got these two:

Inversed side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="RentOrder", mappedBy="calendarEntry")
 */
private $rentOrder;
```

Inversing side (owner):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CalendarEntry", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"all"}, inversedBy="rentOrder")
     */
        private $calendarEntry;
```

And now this works:

```
$rentOrder->getCalendarEntry();
```

But this returns NULL:

```
$calendarEntry->getRentOrder()
```

Why?

// EDIT

Using "fetch" with this annotation doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your DB scheme, both entites has reference to each other. Its a bidirectional relation, so then you save it set relation on both sides, example

```
$rentOrder->setCalendarEntry($calendarEntry);
$calendarEntry->setRentOrder($rentOrder);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Huh? I don't want to store nor change nor set any data. I want to get it.